# pandas: Finding total number of hours per grouped activity

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a set of data:

| Index | Time | MODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-10-24 16:01:01 | Towing Operation |
| 1 | 2020-10-24 15:59:01 | Towing Operation |
| 2 | 2020-10-24 14:59:02 | Towing Operation |
| 3 | 2019-05-24 18:06:01 | Standby at Mooring Buoy |
| 4 | 2019-05-24 18:05:01 | Standby at Mooring Buoy |
| 5 | 2019-05-24 18:03:01 | Standby at Mooring Buoy |

I have tried to groupby each MODE, but I can't return the total time in hours elapsed in each MODE.

What I need is:

| MODE | Total hours elapsed |
| --- | --- |
| Towing Operation | 345hrs |
| Standby at Mooring Buoy | 54hrs |

And it cannot be done by subtracting the earliest date by the latest date, since different MODES will occur at different time of the day.

So after grouping the data, it would look something like this

| MODE | Time |
| --- | --- |
| Towing Operation | 2019-06-18 20:24:01 |
| Towing Operation | 2019-06-26 00:08:02 |
| Towing Operation | 2019-07-02 03:25:02 |
| Standby at Mooring Buoy | 2020-10-21 06:59:02 |
| Standby at Mooring Buoy | 2020-10-21 07:59:02 |
| Standby at Mooring Buoy | 2020-10-21 08:59:02 |

There are a total of 13 different MODES, and I need the total number of hours elapsed only when it is in that MODE.

I hope the question is clear enough! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect your sample data set if not representative of what you are trying to achieve "subtracting the earliest date by the latest date, since different MODES will occur at different time of the day."  are you look for total time of each operation in the day or where you have multiple concurrent events,  you want to aggregate?

Answer (score 0):

You describe that there is a relationship between **Time** and **MODE**.  If this relationship is multiple operations with times, followed by another operation you can use the technique of sorting, find changes by comparing `shift()` and `cumsum()` of this binary series.

```
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""                      Time                     MODE
Index                                              
0      2020-10-24 16:01:01         Towing Operation
1      2020-10-24 15:59:01         Towing Operation
2      2020-10-24 14:59:02         Towing Operation
3      2019-05-24 18:06:01  Standby at Mooring Buoy
4      2019-05-24 18:05:01  Standby at Mooring Buoy
5      2019-05-24 18:03:01  Standby at Mooring Buoy"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")

# data type and sorting is key for grouping
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"])
df = df.sort_values("Time")

# a group is defined as a change in "MODE", so concurrent activities are grouped
df2 = df.groupby(pd.Series(~df["MODE"].eq(df["MODE"].shift()), name="grp").cumsum()).agg(
    MODE=("MODE", "first"),
    count=("MODE", "size"),
    start=("Time", "first"),
    end=("Time","last")
).assign(hours=lambda d: (d["end"]-d["start"]).apply(lambda td: td.seconds/(60*60)))
```

| grp | MODE | count | start | end | hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Standby at Mooring Buoy | 3 | 2019-05-24 18:03:01 | 2019-05-24 18:06:01 | 0.05 |
| 2 | Towing Operation | 3 | 2020-10-24 14:59:02 | 2020-10-24 16:01:01 | 1.03306 |

Answer (score 0):

This answer depends on the `Time` column being type `datetime`.

```
df.groupby('MODE',as_index=False)['Time'].apply(lambda x: (x.max()-x.min()).seconds/3600) \
    .rename(columns={"Time": "Hours"})

                      MODE     Hours
0  Standby at Mooring Buoy  0.050000
1         Towing Operation  1.033056
```